# Getting a corrupted file whenever i try to download anything using this php script except txt file

Tags: php, file, download

Whenever i run this script , i get  a corrupted file .Downloading is happening but i get a corrupted file .let it be a zip file ,img file ,only txt files are working good.Plz help

```
<?php
function download($file){
$file="1.jpg";
$dir = './files/';
$path = $dir.$file;
if(!file_exists($path)){
    die('Error');
}else{
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($path));
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
    readfile($path);

}
}

    download("1.jpg");


?>
```

Comment: what ? do i do with this 
   
 
filesize($path) ????????????????

Comment: you're doing `filesize('kittens.jpg')` instead of `filesize('/path/to/kittens.jpg')`, so filesize fails, returns boolean false, which then gets converted to a zero-length string for your length header. And what's the point of doing ob_start()? That'll just cache your file in memory, and if that's a large file, you can quite easily kill php with an out-of-memory error.

Comment: Please keep the original question as is and do not fix the errors in the code based on answers and comments, it will become irritating to those who try to answer, or people who find this question later with the same problem.

Comment: i get vote downs if i dont

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are desperately trying to force a file download in php, then you can redirect to the url of your file using:

```
header("Location: $path");
```

This method is very frequently used, especially if the file doesn't have a [MIME](https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/) type which is supported by the browser.
However, if you do know the [MIME](https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/) type of the file you want to be download, it is strongly recommended that you use the appropriate Content-type header for that purpose.For instance, if you want to force a jpg file download (as in your example) then you will have to use something like this:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($path));
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
readfile($path);
```

Comment: Not Working bro, i will accept ur answer ,have already upvoted it ,but i want it 2 work

Comment: all i see is that "windows photo viewer cant open it coz the image is corrupted damaged or too large"

Comment: File appears corrupted ,y ?

Comment: @PoKeMoNG0 Your code, after the suggested modifications seems perfectly fine and is working on my xampp test server.Maybe the problem is with your jpeg file.Could you give me more information about the server you are trying to download your file?

Comment: Checked it on some other pc, thnx for helpign it is just not working on my pc . SO much thnx ,awarding u point now

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
```

To

```
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
```

You're setting the `Content-Length: 0` because instead of passing the full path to `filesize()` you pass in just the file name. As a result, the browser disconnects without downloading any byte and you get an empty file.

You should also remove these 3 lines

```
ob_clean();
ob_start();
flush();
```

Because `readfile()` alone is sufficient to stream to the browser. There is nothing in the buffer that needs flushing if you've shown us the whole script

Comment: code updated ob_clean();
ob_start();
flush(); these r removed

Comment: @PoKeMoNG0 screaming at me doesn't make me want to help. I also have problems of my own I'm trying to solve :-)   Have you tried clearing your browser's cache and restarting? or restarting in private browsing mode?  does the image show up in the browser if you change the content type with `header('Content-Type: image/jpg`)`? (replace your current type to test)

Comment: no not working ,just do 1 thing ,suggest me sum webpage  where i can get code to allow users to download files (php script).It should b working .I will accept ur answer then

Comment: yes i tried whatever u have said so far , not working

Comment: all i see is that "windows photo viewer cant open it coz the image is corrupted damaged or too large"

Comment: file is getting downloaded ,same ize before download n after downlaod but corrupted ,y ?

Comment: @PoKeMoNG0 try my code with a simple `.txt` file. Maybe my script is fine but the image file is bad.

Comment: question has been changed completely already, i told u .txt files r working fine but zip ,png ,etc not working fine

Comment: image is absolutely fine